# How can I view the Live HTTP Headers sent/received by an iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, http-headers, router

How can I view the Live HTTP Headers sent/received by an iPhone App (the iPhone connects to the internet via a local WiFi router)?

I'm thinking something similar to the Live HTTP Headers plugin for Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a free solution I just found and tried, and it worked beautifully to capture GET/POST requests (which is exactly what I needed):

http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2009/06/sniff-your-iphones-network-traffic/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a guide to doing this using Charles, a proxy application.

http://blog.mediarain.com/2009/08/iphone-http-connection-debugging/

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a free solution that I already found.

Answer (score 1):

[Debookee](http://www.iwaxx.com/debookee) can intercept the traffic of your iPhone and will show you all its HTTP headers in real time.

Disclaimer: I'm one of its developers

Comment: This doesn't seem to be available for iOS as of the date I write this comment.  (Only OS X)

Comment: Only OS X indeed, but the question was not iOS related, ProgrammerGirl suggested Firefox and finally has choosen a proxy in OS X. The advantage of Debookee vs a proxy is that you don't have any configuration to do on the iPhone, no proxy to configure.

Comment: "HTTP Headers sent/received by an iPhone App" and "the iPhone connects to the internet" makes it crystal clear that the question is iOS related.